# R - strange behaviour when converting Nx1 data.frame into vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, dplyr

Sometimes I have transpose data.frame if I want convert it into vector :

```
> class(delta_older)
[1] "data.frame"
> dim(delta_older)
[1] 129   1
> head(as.vector(delta_older), 10)
   delta_wiatru
1           -31
2          -112
3          -417
4          -596
5           -13
6           353
7           888
8           359
9           -69
10          520
> head(as.vector(t(delta_older)), 10)
 [1]  -31 -112 -417 -596  -13  353  888  359  -69  520
```

this behaviour is because of thet the `delta_older` contain attributes ?

```
> attributes(delta_older)
$names
[1] "delta_wiatru"

$row.names
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
 [41]  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80
 [81]  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
[121] 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

`delta_older` is product od `dplyr`

Comment: `as.vector()` for an one-column dataframe gives still an one-column dataframe: `B <- BOD[-1]; str(as.vector(B))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `t` you are coercing your data.frame column into a matrix at which point, the attributes are dropped.

```
xy <- data.frame(a = 1:3)
attr(xy, "test") <- "some attribute"

> attributes(xy)
$names
[1] "a"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 3

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$test
[1] "some attribute"

> attributes(t(xy))
$dim
[1] 1 3

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
[1] "a"

$dimnames[[2]]
NULL


> attributes(as.vector(t(xy)))
NULL
```